# MYSQL Search by list of IDs using WHERE

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables: 'videos', 'tags' and 'links'. Here is an example of links table:

```
mysql> select * from links;
+----+-------+---------+
| id | tagid | videoid |
+----+-------+---------+
| 25 |     6 |      35 |
| 24 |     5 |       7 |
| 23 |     1 |       7 |
| 22 |     7 |       3 |
| 21 |     1 |       3 |
+----+-------+---------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

To get tags list for each video I use this query:

```
SELECT v.id, GROUP_CONCAT(l.tagid) as tags FROM videos v LEFT JOIN links l ON l.videoid = v.id GROUP BY v.id;
+----+------+
| id | tags |
+----+------+
| 30 | NULL |
| 31 | 2    |
| 32 | 1,3  |
| 33 | 1    |
| 34 | 1,2  |
+----+------+
5 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

But how can I search for videos, containing a list of tags? Currently I add `HAVING` clause at the end of query.

For example, I have three videos with tags '1', '1,4', '1,4,7'. In order to find videos which contain tags 1 and 4 I add `HAVING sum(tagid = 1) > 0 AND sum(tagid = 4) > 0`. It returns two last videos. This is a solution from similar questions. It would be more convenient to me to use `WHERE` clause, so I am looking for an answer with `WHERE`.

Comment: You want videos which have both tags (1 and 4)?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, yes, I want to search for multiple tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter for with a in clause  the tag you need  and having count(disctinct  tagid) equals  to number of tag you need eg for two tagid named  tagid1, tagid2

```
SELECT v.id, GROUP_CONCAT(l.tagid) as tags 
FROM videos v 
where l.tagid in(  tagid1, tagid2)
LEFT JOIN links l ON l.videoid = v.id GROUP BY v.id
having count(dictinct tagid) = 2;
```

otherwise if you need  also the video that contain the 2 tags but also the others  you should remove the having clause

```
SELECT v.id, GROUP_CONCAT(l.tagid) as tags 
FROM videos v 
where l.tagid in(  tagid1, tagid2)
LEFT JOIN links l ON l.videoid = v.id GROUP BY v.id
```

Or you can use a in clause the video tha match tha tag

```
SELECT v.id, GROUP_CONCAT(l.tagid) as tags 
FROM videos v 
where v.id in (
    select videos.id 
    from videos
    INNER JOIN links on links.videoid = video.id 
          and links.tagid in (  tagid1, tagid2)
) 
GROUP BY v.id
```

Comment: Note that in this case the `tags` column will only contain `tagid1` and `tagid2`, even if the video has more tags.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel  .  correct  ..  answer  updated  .. many thanks

Comment: thx for answer, but second query returns videos which contain only tagid1, only tagid2 and both. but videos should have both tags and also can have more tags, I've updated answer so you can see desired result

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, your actual working query is

```
SELECT v.id, GROUP_CONCAT(l.tagid) as tags
FROM videos v
LEFT JOIN links l ON l.videoid = v.id
GROUP BY v.id
HAVING sum(tagid = 1) > 0
   AND sum(tagid = 4) > 0
```

This (IMHO) is just fine as long as the tables are not too big. However with this HAVING condition your JOIN becomes logically an INNER JOIN. And if you only need the `id` of the videos, you can select `l.videoid` without touching the `videos` table.

```
SELECT l.videoid, GROUP_CONCAT(l.tagid) as tags
FROM links l
GROUP BY l.videoid
HAVING sum(tagid = 1) > 0
   AND sum(tagid = 4) > 0
```

But this requires a full table scan on the `links` table, which might be a performance issue on a big dataset. For a better performance you can try the following query:

```
SELECT l.videoid, GROUP_CONCAT(l.tagid) as tags
FROM links l
JOIN links l1 USING(videoid)
JOIN links l2 USING(videoid)
WHERE l1.tagid = 1
  AND l2.tagid = 4
```

Given indexes on `links(tagid, videoid)` and `links(videoid, tagid)` the execution plan should be:

- Find all rows in `links` (`l1`) with `tagid = 1` (search in index `(tagid, videoid)`)
- Find all rows in `links` (`l2`) with `tagid = 4` and the same `videoid` as in `l1` (search in index `(tagid, videoid)`) and skip all rows without a match.
- Find all rows in `links` (`l`) with the same `videoid` as in `l1` and `l2` and group them by `videoid` (use index `(videoid, tagid)` for search and GROUP BY)

If you need more than just the `videoid` you can still join the `videos` table

```
JOIN videos v ON v.id = l.videoid
```

and select what ever you need from that table.